# performance for reads of nsdictionary vs nsarray

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, performance, benchmarking

Continuing off this post: [Performance hit incurred using NSMutableDictionary vs. NSMutableArray>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098174/performance-hit-incurred-using-nsmutabledictionary-vs-nsmutablearray)

I am trying to run a little test to see if the performance gap is that great for read and writes between NSArray & NSDictionary as well as their mutable coutnerparts...

However, I am having difficulties finding a "balanced" test... because the dictionary has 2 (or 3 depending on how you see this) objects to loop through to get the value (not the key) seeked, while the array has only one...

Any suggestions?

--**If you want more details:**
What I mean is easier to explain through examples;

For the array:
(for NSString *str in array) { do smth with the string }

For the dictionary

```
(for NSString *str in [dictionary allValues]) { string }
```

OR

```
(for NSString *str in [dictionary allKeys]) { [dictionary valueForKey:key] }
```

OR

```
(for NSString *str in [dictionary allKeys]) { string }
```

OR EVEN

```
NSArray *valuesOrKeys = [dictionary allKeys/allValues];

(for NSString *str in valuesOrKeys) {string }
```

What is the "fairest" test to do for the dictionary?

--EDIT (comment)

As you all pointed (and asked why I would want that) that when a dictionary is used, it's because it fits the model better than an array...

well the reason for my asking is that an app I'm building is painfully slow and so I'm trying to figure out if the use of a different datatype would change any of that, and I am considering using basic c arrays... I have the choice at this point so I am able to change the inner workings to fit whatever type I want...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd like to point you at the following article: "[Array](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html)", by [ridiculous_fish](http://twitter.com/ridiculous_fish), an engineer at Apple. Cocoa arrays are not necessarily well-implemented naïve arrays as you might expect, nor are dictionaries simple hash tables. Their performance is very circumstantial, and depends on the number of objects they hold (as well as their values, etc.). This might not directly affect the answer, but it's something to consider (`NSDictionary` performance will, of course, vary with the speed and reliability of your hashing function, and so on).

Additionally, if you're looking for a 'balanced' test, you'd have to look for a way for both classes to behave as close to each other as possible. You want to rule out accessing values via keys in the dictionary, because that — regardless of how fast seek times are for the underlying data structures maintained by `NSDictionary` — is slower than simply pulling objects from an array because you're performing more operations to do it. Access from an array is `O(1)`, for a hash table, `O(1)` at best and `O(n)` at worst (depending on the implementation, somewhere in the middle).

There are several ways to enumerate both dictionaries and arrays, as you mentioned above. You're going to want to use the methods that are closest to each other in terms of implementation, those being either block-based enumeration (`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` for `NSArray` and `enumerateKeysAndObjects:` for `NSDictionary`), or fast enumeration (using either `allKeys` or `allValues` for the `NSDictionary`). Because the performance of these algorithms is mainly empirical, I performed several tests to note access times (each with 10000 `NSNumber` objects):

```
NSArray, Block Enumeration:
1. 10.5s
2.  9.1s
3. 10.0s
4.  9.8s
5.  9.9s
   -----
    9.9s Avg

NSArray, Fast Enumeration:
1.  9.7s
2.  9.5s
3.  9.3s
4.  9.1s
5. 10.5s
   -----
    9.6s Avg

NSDictionary, Block Enumeration
1. 10.5s
2. 10.6s
3.  9.9s
4. 11.1s
5. 11.0s
   -----
   10.6s Avg

NSDictionary, allKeys -> Fast Enumeration
1. 10.0s
2. 11.2s
3. 10.2s
4. 10.8s
5. 10.8s
   -----
   10.6s Avg

NSDictionary, allValues -> Fast Enumeration
1. 10.7s
2. 10.3s
3. 10.5s
4. 10.5s
5.  9.7s
   -----
   10.3s Avg
```

As you can see from the results of this contrived test, `NSDictionary` is clearly slower than `NSArray` (around 7% slower using block enumeration, and 7–10% slower with fast enumeration). However, this comparison is rather pointless, seeing as using the fastest enumeration for `NSDictionary` simply devolves it into an array anyway.

So the big question is, why would you consider using a dictionary? Arrays and hash tables aren't exactly interchangeable; what kind of model do you have that allows drop-in replacement of `NSArray` with `NSDictionary`? Regardless of the times given by contrived examples to prove performance benefits one way or another, you should always implement your models in a way that makes *sense* — you can optimize later for performance if you have to. I don't see how you would uses these data structures interchangeably, but anyway, `NSArray` is the winner here, especially considering the sequential order in which you're attempting to access values.

Comment: This answer assumes that creating an array of the values and then enumerating that array is the fastest way to enumerate the contents of a dictionary. That's certainly not guaranteed, and may or may not be true. In fact, there are no performance guarantees, so the best bet is to use the fast enumeration policy. So what you want is -[NSDictionary objectEnumerator]. Or, possibly better, remove the loop and call enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: (and then, to be fair, call enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: on the array). The other points here are all valid, however.

Comment: Actually, objectEnumerator isn't even guaranteed to be direct fast enumeration, so the block method is the only way to be sure you're going as fast as possible. Here are the numbers I got off a quick test: -[NSDictionary allValues] 3.60, directly enumerating NSDictionary's keys and then calling objectForKey: 2.12, -[NSDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]: 0.33. By comparison, directly enumerating NSArray: 0.02, [NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] 0.07. Of course these numbers aren't necessarily meaningful, but they do prove that [allValues] is not a relevant test.

Comment: @abarnert Hat tip to you, great points; however, is there any indication that `enumerate...` invokes fast enumeration ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html) doesn't mention anything about it)? I'll do some of my own testing to back your numbers, and then I'll update my answer.

Comment: @abarnert Actually, my testing indicates that simply retrieving values and enumerating is faster than using either the keys method or block enumeration (across multiple tests using a dictionary containing 10000 values). I'm going to update my answer with the results.

Comment: @abarnert I've updated my answer with various timings which don't completely match up with yours (judging by the times, we're using differently-sized array and dictionary sizes — again, implementation differs due to the contents of the array or dictionary, so this is pretty tough to get right). But anyway, I hope the answer fully complements the question.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your "balanced" test using fast enumeration:

```
[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something with objects    
}];
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something with objects    
}];
```

Comment: As explained in the comments to Itai Ferber's answer, this does seem to be the fairest test. The only real problem is that it's forcing array enumeration to incur block-calling overhead, which isn't necessary (although it is necessary for dictionaries, at least as of the 10.7 SDK). Also, as Itai Ferber explained, the entire test is kind of silly. But if you do insist on a test, this is probably the best one.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to run a little test to see if the performance gap is that
>   great for read and writes between NSArray & NSDictionary as well as
>   their mutable coutnerparts...

Why? If it's just to satisfy your curiosity, that's one thing. But usually if you need a dictionary, an array really won't do, and vice versa. So it doesn't matter which one is faster at a given operation -- it's not like one is good alternative for the other.

> However, I am having difficulties finding a "balanced" test... because
>   the dictionary has 2 (or 3 depending on how you see this) objects to
>   loop through to get the value (not the key) seeked, while the array
>   has only one...

You're making some assumptions here that aren't likely to be valid. There's probably not a lot of looping involved to access elements of either kind of container.